# Display IP ADDRESS in Html.Label using Viewdata

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

I am trying to pass IP address to my view using `ViewData` but it isn't displaying correctly. Below is my coding for label:

`@Html.Label(ViewData["CREATED_LOC"].ToString(), new { @class = "form-control", @disabled = "disabled" })`

I inspected in my model, the data fetched is in string "10.200.4.7" but in my view it only displays 7. May i know what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ViewBag...
ViewBag using in c# controller:

```
ViewBag.IpAddress = Request.UserHostAddress;
```

after then u can use in view like this(display:none for your choice):

```
<span id="spnIpAddress" style="display:none">@ViewBag.IpAddress</span>
```

if you can use this ip address in ajax request. u can use like this:

```
_ipAddress: $('#spnIpAddress').text(),
```